How do I compute the hash for a client secret when using parameterised configuration
I'm using parameterised configuration for deploying curity. I am storing my secrets in AWS, I want to pull the secrets during pipeline deployments hash them and deploy them using environmental secrets in fargate.
When I test the locally with the UI, it seems a given secret can hash to different values when I inspect the XML configuration.
Is there a consistent way to hash a secret?
I was expecting the hashing on the UI to be consistent, and for there to be a documented way to programmatically hash the secrets for parameterised deployment

You can use openssl to hash the values for client secrets or use the ./bin/crypttools script of the Curity Identity Server
CLIENT_SECRET='Password1'
CLIENT_SECRET_HASH=$(openssl passwd -5 "$CLIENT_SECRET")

or
CLIENT_SECRET='Password1'
CLIENT_SECRET_HASH=$(./bin/crypttools -p "$CLIENT_SECRET")

The hash includes a salt, i.e. some random data. This explains the different values.
FYI, Curity has a tutorial about GitOps that walks through various options and also handles parameterized config with secure values. The details are in one of the scripts that accompany the tutorial: https://github.com/curityio/idsvr-gitops-configuration-management/blob/main/vault/create-secure-environment-data.sh
